# Scientific book about time travel?

Tags: resource-recommendations, time-travel

Is there any book which is related with time travel? I want to read something scientific about it. I read Michio Kaku's Physics of the Impossible but in there just one chapter was about time travel. I found some papers on arxiv. However, they were beyond my knowledge. 
Could you suggest me some book about time travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't a lot of books specifically related to time-travel issues, but here are some that have a decent part of them related to the issue :

**Matt Visser, "Lorentzian wormholes"**

Mostly related to wormholes, as the title implies. As one important aspect of wormholes is their ability to generate closed timelike curves, it has a decent section on spacetimes with closed timelike curves, their effects on quantum fields and other such issues. While more of a reference book than a proper derivation for every problem, it's fairly mathy.

**John Earman, "Bangs, Crunches, Whimpers, and Shrieks"**

Earman is entirely dedicated to weird issues related to general relativity, such as singularities, closed timelike curves, the initial value problem, supertasks, horizons and other such problems. Also mostly a reference book rather than a proper repository of proofs (there's some sketches of proofs), but still quite a lot of math. Earman also wrote "A primer on determinism", which also contains a bit on time travel in physics.

**Enrico Rodrigo, "The physics of stargates"**

A book without any advanced math on the topic of wormholes, similarly to Visser's book but aimed at a more general audience.

**Alan Everett, Thomas Roman, "Time travel and warp drives"**

A book on various spacetimes featuring closed timelike curves (and faster-than-light spacetimes) aimed at the general public.

Edit : Fairly recent addition :

**Serguei Krasnikov, Back-in-Time and Faster-than-Light Travel in General Relativity**

A book from a fairly well-versed theorist on the topic, it goes over quite a lot of very specific theoretical matters concerning time travel. I would quite recommend that one on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

In the excellent [**Kip Thorne's**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip_Thorne) book ["**Black Holes and Time Warps**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Holes_and_Time_Warps) there is a chapter on time travel entitled

"*Wormholes and Time Machines, in which the author seeks insight into Physical Laws by asking: can highly advanced civilizations build wormholes through hyperspace for rapid interstellar travel and machines for travelling backward in time?*"

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have also found a book on time travelling that I have read some years ago:

*J. Richard Gott - Time Travel in Einstein's Universe: The Physical Possibilities of Travel Through Time*

I have read it at the beginning of my physics studies and it was very understandable, there is no advanced math in it. It aims at the general public and I remember that I found it quite enjoyable.